# Select data from database where values in a column are different

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I dont know how exactly to put the topic to fit what i want to achieve. If you can , kindly help restructure it.

I have a database whose structure looks like this

```
Transaction ID  tx_no
xxx 12
xxx 12
xxx 12
xxy 17
xxy 12
qqq 18
qqq 18
qqq 18
yty 15
yty 14
yty 15
```

I want to select the field where the transaction ID's are the same but the tr no is not the same all through for a transaction ID

e.g i want my query to select yty, xxy.

I would appreciate any help i can get with this either with php or mysql.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be one way:

```
SELECT transactionid
FROM tablename
GROUP BY transactionid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tx_no) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select transactionid
from tablename
group by transactionid
having max(tx_no) <> min(tx_no)
```

You can try this.